# Where is security.ubuntu.com for old-releases?

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu 10 to 12 and have amended archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com. But there is still failure in resolving for security.ubuntu.com. What should be the correct URL for old release of security link?

Here's the sources.list:

```
# 
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 8.04.3 _Hardy Heron_ - Release amd64 (20090709)]/ hardy main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 8.04.3 _Hardy Heron_ - Release amd64 (20090709)]/ hardy main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository. This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is
## offered by Canonical and the respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu
## users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hardy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hardy partner

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

Comment: To add the contents of a file, paste them, select them with a mouse, and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get update` work with the `http://` added in?

Answer (score 6):

The correct link is still **old-releases.ubuntu.com**

There isn't any equal of `security.ubuntu.com` on these old archive, so just stick with main link.

See also: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported releases ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still getting No candidate ver: xxx with the warning: Failed to read mirror file.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/854856/edit) your post and post `/etc/apt/sources.list` content

Comment: Current sources.list added to main post.

Comment: Have you tried change prompt to lts ?

Comment: When I execute: sudo do-release-upgrade, I can see that it is upgrading to Precise, which is Ubuntu 12 LTS right?

Comment: Yup, 12.04 codename is precise pangolin

Comment: I have check /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades, I do see: Prompt=lts already configured.

Comment: I check /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and see these: ERROR Unauthenticated packages found... abort called

Comment: I think thats for [new](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) question, consider accept this answer if you think it's helpful.

Comment: What about this error: No candidate ver: xxx with the warning: Failed to read mirror file. 

Not sure if it can't read from old-releases or archive site. But something isn't right. The upgrade is grabbing files from sg.archive.ubuntu.com (I'm in Singapore)